# How to resolve link error "undefined reference to `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT`"?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw-w64, virtual-disk

Consider the following program `example.c`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <virtdisk.h>

int main() {
    VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE storageType = {VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_DEVICE_ISO, VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT};
    HANDLE virtualDiskHandle;
    OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS openParameters;
    ULONG result;
    LPCWSTR isoPath = L"path_to_iso_file.iso";
    result = OpenVirtualDisk(&storageType, isoPath, VIRTUAL_DISK_ACCESS_READ, OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE, &openParameters, &virtualDiskHandle);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return 1;
    }
    CloseHandle(virtualDiskHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

I try compiling it using MinGW-w64, but I get this error:

```
# gcc -Wall -Wextra example.c -lvirtdisk
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\tools\msys64\tmp\cciUwbcG.o:example.c:(.rdata$.refptr.VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT[.refpt
r.VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT]+0x0): undefined reference to `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I need to link against to get `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT`? `-lvirtdisk` is enough for `OpenVirtualDisk` but doesn't to work for that.

I tried manually defining the GUID in `example.c`:

```
DEFINE_GUID(VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT, 0xec984aec, 0xa0f9, 0x47e9, 0x90, 0x1f, 0x71, 0x41, 0x5a, 0x66, 0x34, 0x5b);
```

But I still get the same error doing that.

I realise my `OpenVirtualDisk` invocation may well be wrong, and might not work without further changes. But all I'm asking about here is getting it to link.

`gcc --version` says:

```
gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I tried `clang` instead but got the same error.

Comment: Does it work with `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_UNKNOWN`?

Comment: @user694733 no, `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_UNKNOWN` gives same result. Brecht Sanders' answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need both `-lvirtdisk` and `-luuid` linker flags.

- `-lvirtdisk` for `OpenVirtualDisk`
- `-luuid` for `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT`

Comment: `-luuid` works fine. Another solution that appears to work just as well is `#include <initguid.h>` at the top of the C file (before `#include <windows.h>`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could follow the following steps to solve the issue:

1, You should link the `virtdisk.lib`: #pragma comment(lib, "virtdisk.lib")

2, According to the Doc：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/ns-virtdisk-virtual_storage_type

VendorId

> Vendor-unique identifier.
>
> VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT
> (EC984AEC-A0F9-47e9-901F-71415A66345B)

You should provide the identifier of `VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT`:

```
static const GUID VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT = { 0xEC984AEC, 0xA0F9, 0x47e9, 0x90, 0x1F, 0x71, 0x41, 0x5A, 0x66, 0x34, 0x5B };
```

Comment: Have you got any updates? May I know if you have got any chance to check my suggestion?

Comment: Point (1) doesn't work – I'm using mingw-w64, which doesn't accept `#pragma comment(lib, "virtdisk.lib")`, that's MSVC only. Point (2) doesn't work either – `error: static declaration of 'VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT' follows non-static declaration`. Brecht Sanders' answer worked though

Comment: Actually, regarding (2), this variant of it does work: `const GUID VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT = { 0xEC984AEC, 0xA0F9, 0x47e9, { 0x90, 0x1F, 0x71, 0x41, 0x5A, 0x66, 0x34, 0x5B } };`. However, Brecht Sanders' solution above is better, since I don't need to duplicate the GUID from the header, just add `-luuid` to the `gcc` invocation